# minimum hamming distance between strings

Tags: python

Im trying to find the minimum hamming distance between a given string (crib) and another string (msg).

This is the code i have so far:

```
def min_hamming_distance(crib, msg):
    word_list=msg.split()
    ham_dist=0
    ham_dist_list=[]
    for word in word_list:
        if len(word)==len(crib):
            for i in range(len(crib)):
                if word[i] != crib[i]:
                    ham_dist+=1
            ham_dist_list.append(ham_dist)
    if ham_dist_list == []:
        return 0
    return min(ham_dist_list)
```

this code works for me up until I test the "crib" to be anything longer than 1 word. How can I fix this so that "crib" can be 2 or more words?

Comment: Suppose `crib="foo"` and `msg="qx"`. What should be the outcome?

Comment: You also forgot to *reset* the `ham_dist` counter when you analyze a new word.

Comment: the code only analyzes words of the same size, so for hello and jellx, the hamming distance would be 2